# Маршрутизация и интернет

Tags: сеть, windows-server, маршрутизация, маршрутизатор

есть две сети 172.22.47.0/24 и 192.168.1.0/24первая сеть уходит по VPN на другую сеть 172.16.0.0/24а вторая имеет выход в интернет через роутеркак объединить 1 и 2 сеть чтоб 2-я видела рабочие станции 1-ой?*есть комп с двумя картами и ОС Windows server 2003

Answer (score 1):

Единый шлюз для всех!Вопрос не раскрыт до конца. Я так понимаю, что есть 3 сети одна из которых за VPN !

> На шлюзе сети 172 указать где находится сеть 192, где маршрут в сеть будит через шлюз сети 192 .При этом шлюз 192 сети должен смотреть в обе сети ...Или поднять маршрутизатор который будит смотреть во все сети и на шлюзах указать его в качестве шлюза в др сеть.

Comment: дело в том что сеть 172 смотрит в сторону VPN шлюз например 172.22.47.1 а в сети 192 в сторону роутера интернета шлюз 192.168.1.1 нужно чтоб эта сеть так же выходила на VPN го сеть 172 не должна выходить в интерент

Comment: Нужно ставить роутер чтоб смотрел во все сети ,а на шлюзах где инет прописать статические маршруты , VPN фильтровать